# Generate TextMate language grammar from PEG.js grammar

Tags: syntax-highlighting, grammar, textmate, peg, pegjs

Is there a tool that translates a PEG.js grammar to a [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) grammar?

I am building my own language and would like to have syntax highlighting for it in my preferred editor, TextMate. The grammar of my language is built with [PEG.js](http://pegjs.majda.cz/). According to the  [TextMate documentation](http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars) for this use-case, I have to write the TextMate grammar in a form that is incompatible with PEG.js.

I started writing a new TextMate grammar, but I quickly noticed that it takes quite a while to translate the whole grammar, or even the subset relevant for an acceptable syntax highlighting. Since I am incredibly lazy and don't want to do all this tedious work, I thought about automating this task.

Can anyone give me any clues how to automate, or at least speed up, the generation of TextMate grammar from a PEG.js grammar?

Comment: https://github.com/alexstrat/PEGjs.tmbundle

Comment: This bundle only adds syntax highlighting for PEG.js grammar files. What I want is syntax highlighting for files that are written in a language defined by a PEG.js grammar.

Comment: Unfortunately this would be hard - TextMate uses patterns whereas PEG.js uses byte-based comparisons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can anyone give me any clues how to automate, or at least speed up, the generation of TextMate grammar from a PEG.js grammar?

Use the following process:

- Understand Regular Expressions
- Understand Parsing Expression Grammars
- Create a mapping table based on the similarities
- Create functions based on the differences

**References**

- [Problems with an ambiguous grammar and PEG.js (no examples found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659684/1113772)
- [What is the best way to define grammars for a text editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170180/1113772)
- [What are the differences between PEGs and CFGs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501074/1113772)